# How to retrieve attribute name as string in python

Tags: python, pointers, attributes

I want to retrieve attribute name to create something like pointer in python, for now I use the following statement but i'm not satistified:

```py
class foo:
   name: str
   last_name: str

class other:
   def __init__(self, obj, var):
        obj.__dict__[var] = "John"
        

f = foo("Jon", "Jon")
o = other(f, "name")
```

I want to write

```py
o = other(f, f.name)
```

or better

```py
o = other(f.name)
```

I tried some func to retrive name but it only work with object and not attribute of object :

```py
def retrieve_name(var: object) -> str:
    for objname, oid in globals().items():
        if oid is var:
            return objname
        if hasattr(oid, "__dict__"):
            for child in oid.__dict__:
                # dont work because id is the same if value is the same
                if id(oid.__dict__[child]) == id(var):
                    return child
```

this code only work if I use `retrieve_name(f) -> f` but not if I use `retrieve_name(f.last_name) -> name` if `f.name == f.last_name` because `id(f.name) == id(f.last_name)` when string value are the same

Comment: According to your idea, after the creation is successful, what is its use or how will you use it?

Comment: I made a game and other is in fact a button who can modify another object atribute value : for exemple the pause button should interact with `game.pause` boolean

Comment: Can a button bind multiple objects?

Comment: It looks like qt's signals, will using signals meet your needs?

Comment: It could bind to some object, but i don't want to transform all attribute I use with setter and getter

I'll see if signals are adequate in my case

Answer (score 0):

If it is to bind an object, whether this will meet your needs simply and quickly.

[`object.__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__setattr__#object.__setattr__)

> Called when an attribute assignment is attempted. This is called instead of the normal mechanism (i.e. store the value in the instance dictionary). name is the attribute name, value is the value to be assigned to it.

```py
class foo:
    name: str = ""
    last_name: str = ""


class other:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__dict__["obj"] = obj

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not hasattr(self, key) and hasattr(self.__dict__["obj"], key):
            setattr(self.__dict__["obj"], key, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(key, value)


f = foo()
o = other(f)
print("1. ", f.name, f.last_name)
o.name = "Jon"
print("2. ", f.name, f.last_name)

"""
1.   
2.  Jon 
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for you propotion but `obj.__dict__[var] = "John"` work perfectly but i'll try `__setattr__` who seem to bee better looking and efficient, i just wanted other to know about attribute name,

In fact i got 10 buttons with a generic code, I just want a way to get attribute name as a string